# How to get number of rows using due date/ expiry date in codeigniter?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

Table Name: `directives`

```
dir_id  |  directive  |  due_date |
-----------------------------------
1       |  some text  |  2017-03-30 02:00:00
2       |  some text  |  2016-04-30 02:00:00
3       |  some text  |  2017-04-30 02:00:00
4       |  some text  |  2016-03-30 02:00:00
5       |  some text  |  2015-04-30 02:00:00
6       |  some text  |  2016-04-30 02:00:00
```

using three conditions.

`if` there are `60 days` left to due date show `green` `elseif`there are `5 days` left show `yellow` `else if` there are `zero(0) days or minus days` passed due date show `red` .

Also if possible get number of rows respectively `*You can use different query for row count*` e.g rows with `60 days left = 5, data with 5 days left = 4, data with 0 days or minus = 4`

*'Lovely day to all'*

Thank you

### ** Final Edit "Working Code for row count"**

```
   //For Zero days
   $this->db->where('due_date < now()');
   $query0 = $this->db->count_all_results('directives');

   //For five days left
   $this->db->where('due_date between now() - interval 6 day and now() + interval 5 day');
   $query5 = $this->db->count_all_results('directives');

   //For more than 5+ days left
   $this->db->where('due_date > now() + interval 6 day');
   $query6 = $this->db->count_all_results('directives');
```

**In case I did not follow the standard procedure please let me know.**

Thank you

Comment: Please share if you have tried something ?

Comment: Use date_diff() in your DB Query

Comment: @Kunal thanks for the reply, could you show me how i can insert `date_diff` in query new in codeigniter @Rishi I have done some editing and included the code i tried.

Comment: You aren't passing a table to count all results to. `$this->db->count_all_reults('table');`

Comment: @Kisaragi when I pass the table as you said i get 0 i.e 
`$this->db->where('directives.due_date <', now());
                        $count_query = $this->db->count_all_results('directives');
                        print_r($count_query);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

/**UNTESTED**/

```
select case
    when due_date between now() - interval 5 day and sysdate()
       then "red"
    when due_date between now() - interval 6 day and now() - interval 59 day
       then "Yellow"
when due_date > now() + interval 60 day
       then "Green"
end as age,
sum(case when due_date between now - interval 5 day and sysdate() then 1 else 0 end) red_count 
 ///// sum others to get counts
from table
```

Comment: That's in SQL. You can build it using codeigniter's active record. Just wrap the select portion in `this->db->select()` etc...

Comment: sorry for bothering you  but am new in codeigniter. I can not seem to convert the sql to codeigniter active record format.